# Group by every N records but remove incomplete group that has records less than N

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to query a table to fetch data in groups of some size say N=5 but if the size is less than 5 then the last group should be ignored

i.e every 5 records should be grouped

> ==> i.e first 5 records form first group
> ==> next 5 records form second group
> ==> next 5 records form third group

....

**What I have tried**

I have tried the below query. It works but it fetches all the data.

**My Requirement**

I need to strip off the last group if it does not have 5 records there.
in below query groupSize is the size of group

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dateReceived ) Rank,
    p.data
  FROM parameterData p where parameterID=@parameterID
        and isActive=1
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS GroupID, (Rank - 1) / @groupSize GroupSize, AVG(data) average, MIN(data) min,MAX(data) max,MAX(data)-MIN(data) range
FROM T
GROUP BY ((Rank - 1) / @groupSize);
```

Comment: Can you create a https://dbfiddle.uk/ with some sample data that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I have added
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfd68fa575c8b4a375f3eb31432a2303

Totally there are 6 rows here
SO we can form only 1 complete group.
Remaing 2 rows should not be considered

Here if groupSize = 4 then only 1 rows should come. But the last  row is fetched using  last 2 rows which is less than the group size(4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  WITH T AS 
(
  SELECT 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dateReceived ) Rank,
    p.data
  FROM parameterData p where parameterID=@parameterID
    and dateReceived between @fromDate and @toDate
    and recipe = @recipe
    and isActive=1
)
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS GroupID, 
  (Rank - 1) / @groupSize as GroupSize, 
  AVG(data) as average, 
  MIN(data) as min,
  MAX(data) as max,
  MAX(data)-MIN(data) as range, 
  count(*) as cnt
FROM T
GROUP BY ((Rank - 1) / @groupSize)
HAVING count(*) = 5;
```

Comment: anyone got a link to how to format code  ?

Comment: Thanks its working for me.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=099bd5b7cce2c9954c82ce69fdd54468